# Mips fsbl code keeps rebooting

Tags: embedded, mips, broadcom

I'm working on Mips R4380 chip and its an embedded system of Broadcom 7xxx platform. I have a code like this:

```
.globl  print_forever;
.ent    print_forever;
.set noreorder

loop:
  PRINT_CHAR('0')
  nop
  b loop
  nop

.set reorder
.end print_forever
```

And the boot up code:

```
__start:
b __rom_init
nop

__rom_init:
.set  noreorder
bal  init_uart
nop
PRINT_CHAR('S')
nop
bal  print_forever
nop
```

All codes are put on flash and __start is located at 0xBFC00000 which is the first instruction location after power on. If print_forever is put in the same .s file with the boot up code (around at 0xBFC01380) then everything is fine, I can see it prints forever. But if print_forever is put in a different .s file (around at 0xBFC07C00) then the system keeps rebooting after printing hundreds of zeros every time (I can see the 'S' after hundreds of 0's).

The code address where print_forever locates should be in a valid boot code area (< 32KB). The code doesn't use any RAM (except writing registers to print the character) and is uncached so cache and memory should not be a problem. I've also tried another board but ended up the same result so the flash should be ok.

I'm not experienced in boot code development. When I was trying to modify the fsbl code I saw this strange problem. So I tried making everything simple but just couldn't understand what the problem could be? Can anyone help me out of this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.